# Nested models form saving: This field is required error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as BaseUser

CHOICE_GENDER = ((1, 'Male'), (2, 'Female'))


class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return ', '.join([self.city, self.state])


class Users(BaseUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(BaseUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICE_GENDER)
    birth = models.DateField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('user',)
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from .models import Users, Location


class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = '__all__'


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'birth', 'location')
```

views.py:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        reg_form = forms.RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        loc_form = forms.LocationForm(request.POST)
        if loc_form.is_valid():
            reg_form.location = loc_form.save()
            if reg_form.is_valid():
                reg_form.save()
                return redirect('./')
    reg_form = forms.RegistrationForm()
    loc_form = forms.LocationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'loc_form': loc_form, 'reg_form': reg_form})
```

I can't manage to make this work, it gives `location - This field is required` error. I've tried every combination in views.py, and it never passed the `reg_form.is_valid()` command due to that reason. Can anybody help me in this? Thanks in advance!

---

SOLVED: views.py new, working code:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        reg_form = forms.RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        loc_form = forms.LocationForm(request.POST)
        if reg_form.is_valid():
            reg = reg_form.save(commit=False)
            if loc_form.is_valid():
                reg.location = loc_form.save()
                reg.save()
                return redirect('./')
    reg_form = forms.RegistrationForm()
    loc_form = forms.LocationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'loc_form': loc_form, 'reg_form': reg_form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `location` from `RegistrationForm` fields tuple should stop the behavior.

Since you are using a separate form for Location, you shouldn't populate `location` field using `RegistrationForm`.

Comment: Great, I understand now and I've solved the problem - it was plain easy though (I'll update the main question with the solution code)! Thanks for the explanation!